# Merging two arrays in a specific way in JavaScript inside React app

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge

I am trying to populate a table with rows and checkboxes using `.map`, but there was a problem creating the array. I have 2 arrays that I get from the database and I need to combine them into 1. Below I left two source arrays (JournalA and JournalB)

**Journal_A**

```
[
  {STUDENT_NAME: "data1",
   STUDENT_SECOND_NAME: "data",
   STUDENT_LAST_NAME: "data",
   STUDENT_PHOTO: "data"
  },
  {STUDENT_NAME: "data2",
   STUDENT_SECOND_NAME: "data",
   STUDENT_LAST_NAME: "data",
   STUDENT_PHOTO: "data"
  },
  {STUDENT_NAME: "data3",
   STUDENT_SECOND_NAME: "data",
   STUDENT_LAST_NAME: "data",
   STUDENT_PHOTO: "data"
  }
]
```

**Journal_B**

```
[{
  JOURNAL_DATA: "{
  "1": false,
  "2": false, 
  "3": false
  }"
}]
```

**And it need to be like below**

```
[
  {STUDENT_NAME: "data1",
   STUDENT_SECOND_NAME: "data",
   STUDENT_LAST_NAME: "data",
   STUDENT_PHOTO: "data",
   BOOL:true
  },
  {STUDENT_NAME: "data3",
   STUDENT_SECOND_NAME: "data",
   STUDENT_LAST_NAME: "data",
   STUDENT_PHOTO: "data",
   BOOL:false
  },
  {STUDENT_NAME: "data2",
   STUDENT_SECOND_NAME: "data",
   STUDENT_LAST_NAME: "data",
   STUDENT_PHOTO: "data",
   BOOL:true
  },
]
```

I've tried using `concat()` and `push()` but React doesn't work with them =(

```
let i = 0;
for (i=0; i<JournalA.length; i++){
    console.log(JournalA.map[i].concat(JournalB.concat[i]));
}
```

Comment: `JournalA.map((item, index) => (item.BOOL = JournalB[0][index + 1], item))`

Comment: Is there only one item in Journal_B Array?

Comment: It seems weird to me that JournalB looks that way. Why don't you make it an array? The code I suggest remains valid but would be simpler.

Comment: It makes ````[
  {BOOL:{JOURNAL_DATA: "{"1": false, "2": false, "3": false}"},
   STUDENT_NAME: "data1",
   STUDENT_SECOND_NAME: "data",
   STUDENT_LAST_NAME: "data",
   STUDENT_PHOTO: "data"
  }
]````

Comment: I'm not very good at programming. It's my course project

Comment: Are you sure Journal_B is an Array? This isn't a valid Array syntax. Shouldn't it be an object after all?

Comment: I can get a merged array from the database but it would be like JournalA+JournalB and I don’t know how to work with it then =(

Comment: You need to update the information in your question. JOURNAL_B like you're showing us isn't possible. This is invalid syntax

Comment: @OlivierKrull, I've got this from browser console. `{JOURNAL_DATA: "{"1": false, "2": false, "3": false}"}` Seems bad?

Comment: This is 1:1 what you get from the console?

Comment: I made Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V

Comment: try this one, but it will not work with `""` wrapping the JOURNAL_DATA object it should be `''`. `const result = Journal_A.map( ( item, idx ) => {
  item.BOOL = JSON.parse( Journal_B.JOURNAL_DATA)[ idx + 1 ];
  return item
} )`

Comment: Please also update your question with the correct JOURNAL_B, the one currently in the question is not the same as the one in your comment.

Comment: Did you still have snippet without JOURNAL_DATA? I think I understood smth...

Comment: I deleted it, but look, something is wrong with the code you provide. If `JOURNAL_DATA` is a STRING (wrapped with `""`) it can be only on a single line. Also, your result in the question should be updated with `false` everywhere. And the outer String enclosure for `JOURNAL_DATA` should be `''`.

Comment: @SerhiyOsmolenko actually I think you can look in my answers edits for the previous snippeds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could this be the answer?

```js
const Journal_A = [
  {STUDENT_NAME: "data1",
   STUDENT_SECOND_NAME: "data",
   STUDENT_LAST_NAME: "data",
   STUDENT_PHOTO: "data"
  },
  {STUDENT_NAME: "data2",
   STUDENT_SECOND_NAME: "data",
   STUDENT_LAST_NAME: "data",
   STUDENT_PHOTO: "data"
  },
  {STUDENT_NAME: "data3",
   STUDENT_SECOND_NAME: "data",
   STUDENT_LAST_NAME: "data",
   STUDENT_PHOTO: "data"
  }
]


const Journal_B = [{
  JOURNAL_DATA: '{"1": false, "2": false, "3": false}'
}]

const jData = JSON.parse( Journal_B[0].JOURNAL_DATA)

const result = Journal_A.map( ( item, idx ) => {
  item.BOOL = jData[ idx + 1 ]
  return item
} )

console.log(result)
```

Comment: It makes all BOOL values false

Comment: @SerhiyOsmolenko Added snipped to answer check it out

Comment: omg... I'm so sorry. I added wrong JournalB info. updated in main post =(

Comment: @SerhiyOsmolenko here you go

Comment: @SerhiyOsmolenko added a new answer

Comment: Puh.. finally ;-) You're welcome. Feel free to accept my answer so I can collect some XP's ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Try this without the for loop

```
let merged_array = Journal_A.map((a, c) => ({
    ...a,
    BOOL: Journal_B[0][c + 1]
}))
```

EDIT

I didn't see Journal_B was an object, you're trying to merge an array with three elements with another with one element, the structure is not very clear in only this snippet of code, but if I were you I'll try to keep things more simple.

EDIT 2

Your syntax is invalid after the edit of Journal_B